Flutter / Dart version pinning prevents me from Git bisecting
I noticed a regression in an open source project (a SwitchListTile is not highlighting on selection), and figured it would be easy to diagnose with Git bisect.
But after checking out an earlier commit, I can't compile it because of dependency issues:

Resolving dependencies...
Note: test_api is pinned to version 0.6.1 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.


Because drift_dev >=1.7.0 <1.7.1 depends on analyzer....

Is there a straightforward way to restore the earlier environment and dependencies, so I can bisect?
I installed flutter (on MS-Windows) following the official documentation, so I have a flutter directory that's added to my $PATH.
Is it as simple as acquiring the right flutter and putting that on my $PATH instead?
The pubspec.yaml contains:
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: 2.3.0-24.1.pre

So presumably I want to download that?

What I ended up doing was downloading the various Flutter APIs referenced in the Git commits I was bisecting, unzipping them, renaming the top-level directory from flutter to flutter-whatever.version, them symlinking flutter to the version I needed. As my path includes flutter/bin, the symlink resolved the reference version. Then a flutter clean and rebuild.
